# Pagination route problems with willdurand hateoas bundle

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, fosrestbundle, hateoas

I'm currently developping some REST web services using Hateoas and I'd like to implement pagination for some longer list display.

Note : Database retrieve logic isn't implemented yet

This is my controller :

```
use Hateoas\Representation\PaginatedRepresentation;
use Hateoas\Representation\CollectionRepresentation;

/**
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"details"})
 * @Doc\ApiDoc(
 *     section="User",
 *     resource=true,
 *     description="Get all catalogs accessible by a User",
 *     requirements={
 *          {
 *          "name"="id",
 *          "dataType"="integer",
 *          "requirement"="\d+",
 *          "description"="The id of the user from which to retrieve"
 *          }
 *     },
 *     output={
 *          "class"="\CatalogV2",
 *          "groups"={"details"}
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function getUserLicencesAction($id, $page = 1, $limit = 10) {
    $service_rustine = $this->container->get('rustine_core.link');
    // Get User corresponding to id
    $user = $service_rustine->getUser($id);

    // Get licences
    $licences = $user->getLicencesRight();

    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $pages = (int)ceil(count($licences) / $limit);

    $collection = new CollectionRepresentation(
        array_slice($licences, $offset, $page * $limit),
        'licences',
        'licences',
        new Exclusion(array("details"))
        );
    $paginated = new PaginatedRepresentation(
        $collection,
        'get_user_licences',
        array("id" => $id),
        $page,
        $limit,
        $pages
        );

    // JSON output
    return $paginated;
}
```

The error I keep having is :

*"Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "get_user_licences"*

The documentation isn't very clear about route parameters and I can't find any example using a non empty array.

The routeparam id given in the parameters array is always ignored in the UrlGenerator.
I've tried array($id) but it isn't working either.

When I try, in the same controller to generate the route with like this, there is no problem :

```
$this->get('router')->generate('get_user_licences', array('id' => $id));
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it. Even if it fixed this situation, it won't be the only fix for these symptoms, and other people will be able to add other solutions which might help additional people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem : There was actually a YML config file redefining the Hateoas\Representation\PaginatedRepresentation metadata ... The expressions used for the parameters in the route definitions were incorrect. For the "next" link for example I had :

```
expr(object.getPage() + 1)
```

instead of the

```
expr(object.getParameters(object.getPage() + 1))
```

Maybe this will help someone one day !